# Ajax - multiple validation

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, validation, multiple-instances

I have set up some ajax code to validate multiple fields inside a form using php. The code works like a charm, but I wanna minimize the javascript used.

As you can see at the code below, Im getting the getElements('input') ... that validates all input fields and then getElements('textarea') that validates... ya u know! ;o) Textarea is the last line in the code below and the javascript after that is the same as inpt
I'm validating the input, textarea, selection list, checkbox, etc. in my controller using php, but the code after getting the elements is the EXACT SAME.

**So I was thinking that I might could make a switch case or if else with javascript to loop the elements and only write the duplicated javascript once....**

Could that be done?

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
$('container').getElements('input').addEvent('keyup', function(e){
    //stop the input-tag event
    e = new Event(e).stop();
    //identify which item was activated
    var querystring = this.title;
    var value = this.value;
    var myXHR = new XHR({
        method: 'get',
        onSuccess: function(e){
            var myString = myXHR.response.text;
            var myStringArray = myString.split("###RAWR###");
            $(myStringArray[1]).innerHTML = '<em class="checking">&nbsp;</em>';
            setTimeout( ajax , 3500 );
            function ajax(){
                $(myStringArray[1]).innerHTML = '<em class="'+myStringArray[2]+'">'+myStringArray[0]+'</em>';
            }
        }
    });
    myXHR.send('index2.php?option=com_component&task=validate&value='+value, querystring);
});
$('container').getElements('textarea').addEvent('keyup', function(e){
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the tagnames in an array loop it and call a function with your validation.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    var tagNames = ["input", "textarea", "select"];
    for (var i = 0; i < tagNames.length; i++) 
    {
        validate(tagNames[i]);
    }   
});

function validate(tag)
{
    $('container').getElements(tag).addEvent('keyup', function(e){
        //stop the input-tag event
        e = new Event(e).stop();
        //identify which item was activated
        var querystring = this.title;
        var value = this.value;
        var myXHR = new XHR({
            method: 'get',
            onSuccess: function(e){
                var myString = myXHR.response.text;
                var myStringArray = myString.split("###RAWR###");
                $(myStringArray[1]).innerHTML = '<em class="checking">&nbsp;</em>';
                setTimeout( ajax , 3500 );
                function ajax(){
                    $(myStringArray[1]).innerHTML = '<em class="'+myStringArray[2]+'">'+myStringArray[0]+'</em>';
                }
            }
        });
        myXHR.send('index2.php?option=com_component&task=validate&value='+value, querystring);
    });
}
```

Comment: That looks interesting. So I have to identify each input field with a name tag like <input type="text" name="text"> or <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"> and the for loop search for the name tag? Everything else, html as well as controller validation remains the same??? (Im not a javascript expert...this code took me 30 hours to execute ;o)

Comment: I updated my answer and removed checkbox from the tag list. If you'r using the same validation for all input types, texareas and dropdown boxes it should work.